# Add Vibrancy effect to custom UIButton?

Tags: ios, uivisualeffectview

I've been working with UIVisualEffectView to allow background blur and label/button vibrancy. It works great when you're using native controls but I would like to use the same Vibrancy with custom buttons.

See the example images, storyboard with label,button and 2 custom buttons (png 24bit), the result is working perfectly with label and native button, but custom buttons just disappear. Anyone?

[image: storyboard]  ->  [image: device]

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly take a look at the following github:
https://github.com/a1anyip/AYVibrantButton

or for the swift variant: 
https://github.com/remzr7/RZVibrantButton
note that I did not get the swift variant to work but I used the Objective C button a few times.

Comment: thanks Simon, that was the 1st thing that I've tried when I started having issues with this. I'm afraid it doesn't help, only works with normal buttons with text, can't use it with images which is what I really need, button or not.

Comment: Ok sorry, I guess I misunderstood. Mb this can be helpful? https://github.com/ide/UIVisualEffects or a combination of those two

Comment: thanks! that gives me some clues, I'm gonna look into UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate maybe that's the solution, I'll get back to you. Cheers